# Modify appsettings.Production.json file after publish in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a pretty straightforward question.

In my project.json file, I included "appsettings.Production.json" after "appsettings.json" in the Publish section. This works great, the Production overrides the original values as intended.

However, my question is: am I able to modify the Production json file *after* the project has been published with a text editor? I obviously tried doing this and it didn't work, so maybe there's something I'm missing? Or do I have to republish the entire project again if I want to make any changes to any of the json files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @rook wrote, the first step is to enable `reloadOnChange`:

> [Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-the-built-in-sources): When specifying files as configuration sources, you can optionally specify whether changes to the file should result in the settings being reloaded. This is configured by passing in a true value for the reloadOnChange parameter when calling AddJsonFile or similar file-based extension methods.

But in additional, you also need to change code to use `IOptionsMonitor<>` interface instead of `IOptions<>` in places where options are injected (see [Options Pattern](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects)), otherwise you will notice, that new value has not been applied. Read more in this [post](http://andrewlock.net/reloading-strongly-typed-options-when-appsettings-change-in-asp-net-core-rc2/).

Comment: Yep this did it for me! I did what @rook said and figured it would work and was wondering why it didn't. Didn't know there would be this extra step. Thanks!

Comment: Wow - genuinely surprised at how complicated this was!!

Answer (score 3):

There's a `reloadOnChange` parameter which should do the trick.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json",
 optional: false,
 reloadOnChange: true
);
```

Comment: See the answer above. There's more to do.